# Instance life time of objects in ASP.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In Web API, is a new instance of the controller created each time the server receives a call? Is there any optimization done per client or does the server not care where the call is coming from? Also, what happens to static members? I would assume that this would depend on the number of appdomains loaded, so technically it is possible to have multiple 'unique' instances of the same static variable across the process.

Can someone point me to some official documentation regarding how objects and app domains are brought up and destroyed to handle HTTP requests for Web API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a new instance of a controller for each request, I just can't remember any online documentation of it. Here is a great [poster](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) showing the life cycle and extension points. Here are some great [books](http://www.asp.net/web-api/books) that really dissects Web API and have answered most of my questions about the inner workings of it.

Comment: That poster is the ONLY thing that comes up consistently on every Google search on this topic! :) The poster is useful to understand what happens once the request reaches the server (the lifecycle of the request). Doesn't really help with understanding the lifetime of the object itself.

Comment: I'll check my book tomorrow. It's at my office or I'd look right now.

Comment: Since WebAPI is open source, the code may be the best documentation. Check this class here: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/DefaultHttpControllerActivator.cs There is an internal cache that does not care where the request is coming from. As for statics, and multiple appdomains, I'm not sure here.